# There is no sound in 2.80 but was ok in 2.79

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have started using 2.80
Opening a 2.79 project I have no sound in 2.80 (was ok in 2.79)
What do I do wrong?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
In my preference setting (go to Edit>Preference...) for Audio Device it was by default selected "SDL".
I have changed it now to OpenAl and have the audio working fine.

[image]